# Retrieve whole table in servlet

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm wondering if it is possible to get all rows values from a table which is dynamicaly built.
I wanted to get it back just like other parameters with a request.getParameter(...)

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

My table :

```
<table id="table_produits" >
       <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td style="width: 80px;"><label for="u_codep">Produit </label></td>
              <td><select class="span8" name="id_produit">


    <%
                                                                    List<Produit> l;
                                                                        ProduitDao pdao = new ProduitDao();
                                                                        l = pdao.GetAll();
                                                                        int j = 0;

                                                                        while (j < l.size()) {
                                                                    %>
                                                                    <option value="<%=l.get(j).getId()%>">
                                                                        <%=l.get(j).getLibelle()%></option>
                                                                    <%
                                                                        j++;
                                                                        }
                                                                    %>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td style="width: 35px;"><label for="u_quantite">
                                                                Quantité </label></td>
                                                        <td valign="top"><input type="text" id="u_quantite"
                                                            value="${nouvelleVente.quantité}" name="quantite"
                                                            class="span8" size="50" style="width: 50%;" /></td>
                                                        <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
                                                            onclick="javascript:newLine();"></i>
                                                        <td />
            =                                       </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

Comment: Show your servlet code where you attempt to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just find out how to do this : use getParameterValues()

For example -> String[] produits = request.getParameterValues("id_produit");

Thanks developerwjk for trying to help